# For loop not executing due to empty value in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, for-loop, parse-platform

I read a lot of questions related to this matter on StackOverFlow and I still could not solve the problem. The problem is that events for loop is not running in below code. And I think it is due to empty value. I made a function called "`function`" and querying objects from my class in Parse. All those objects I queried are saved in `HelperClass`'s property `events`. Then, I'm executing for loop 
to add `event.numberOfViews` to sum all numbers in array. I was debugging the code and apparently `events` array is empty. I do not get it because i just put the value in `evetns` array. Help wanted! Thanks

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
HelperClass().function()
}


class HelperClass: NSObject {
    var events: [Event] = []
     var sumOfView: Double?

func function() {
     let eventQuery = PFQuery(className: "Event")
        eventQuery.limit = 1000
        eventQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if (error == nil) {
                self.events = result as? [Event] ?? []
            } else {
                println("Error is \(error)")
            }
        }

for event in events {
            array.append(event.numberOfViews)
        }
      sumOfView = array.reduce(0) {return $0! + $1}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` is executed on another thread. If you want to perform that for loops with the events you need to move it inside the if statement.

```
if (error == nil) {
  self.events = result as? [Event] ?? []
  // perform for loop here
} else {
  println("Error is \(error)")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I wasn't unaware of that problem.

Comment: One question tho. If I have multiple functions like findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock and accessing the values from those functions on mainthread, how should I order the methods? Any suggestions on structuring a function?

Comment: You're welcome. Do any of the functions depend on each other, or are they all independent? The best way to organize operations with dependencies is by using NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.

Comment: They are independent. I'm getting one value from function 1 and the other value from function 2. Then, I am diving the value I got from function 1 by the value I got from function 2 after. In this case, do I use NSOperationQueue? I did not hear things like that.

Comment: In this case you need NSOperations. The division operation depends on both function 1 and function 2. Take a look at this article for more information: http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/

Comment: What a life saver. Thanks!